# How to delete an object of a has_many where the parent object is not yet saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an @activity that has_many :clientships

When creating a new object I assign several Clientship objects but before saving, the user wants to pick out a few to delete.

How would I delete one of the following Clientship objects based on a user-defined client_id?

The collection looks like this:

```
@activity.clientships [
  #<Clientship id: nil, client_id: 1770>,
  #<Clientship id: nil, client_id: 24>,
  #<Clientship id: nil, client_id: 25>,
  #<Clientship id: nil, client_id: 2181,>
]
```

The example code I tried which didn't work (not to mention inefficient):

```
@activity.clientships.map {|o| o.delete if o.client_id==24 }
```

Comment: Is this Clientship already saved to db? Or does it just exist in a form?

Comment: Exist on form as they are new records

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@activity.clienships.delete_if{|o| o.client_id == 24}
```

Comment: `@activity.clientships.delete(24)` should do the trick.
I also advise you to choose carefully between `#destroy` and `#delete`.
If you want to preserve callbacks invocations simply use `#destroy`:    `@activity.clientships.destroy(24)`

Also notice that this also works with ActiveRecord objects:

`client = Client.find(24)`
`@activity.clientships.destroy(client)`